What are the Different Types of Gadgets out There?
Similar to the Knill’s EC gadget and the Steane’s gadget what other kinds of gadgets are there?

Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. What do you mean by gadget? Please provide some references.

D. Gottesman, in Quantum information science and its contributions to mathematics, Proceedings of Symposia in Applied Mathematics, Vol. 68 (2010) pp. 13–58.                                                                                                                    It seems like this is the first place gadgets are mentioned. It is also mentioned in https://repository.kulib.kyotou.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/142173/2/D_Fujii_Keisuke.pdf

usually it seems that gadgets are from the context of fault tolerance

another useful source is from the errorcorrectionzoo with https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/list/quantum_fault_tolerance

On general syndrome extraction gadgets: https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.15403. As for any type of gadget that fault-tolerantly can perform logical operations on a code, they are often specific to particular code constructions.
